# Store list of dictionaries as HTML table

Tags: python, django, dictionary

So I want to store my list of dictionaries in django as an HTML table so that I can use it with [django_tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html). WHat would be the best way to go about this? Right now I have this:

my `view.py`:

```
context = {'campaigns': campaigns, 'ad_account': ad_account}

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Where campaigns looks like:

```
[<Campaign> { "effective_status": "PAUSED", "id": "6038662580877", "name": "test22", "objective": "APP_ENGAGEMENT" }, <Campaign> { "effective_status": "PAUSED", "id": "6038659889677", "name": "just a test", "objective": "APP_ENGAGEMENT" }]
```

I cant use my current method with django_tables because it only accepts a table. WHat I do for now is pasted below and generates a table in its entirety in 1 page which is not feasible as more data is added.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="campaigns">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> #</th>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Objective</th>
        <th> Effective Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for campaign in campaigns %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ forloop.counter }} </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/ad/{{ ad.id }}/campaigns/{{ campaign.id }}/ad_sets">
                    {{ campaign.name }} </a>
            </td>
            <td> {{ campaign.objective }}</td>
            <td> {{ campaign.effective_status }} </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Personally I don't know why people choose to use all kinds of libraries with Django. Django has most of the functionality you need built in. Many of these libs only make life harder.

Comment: but django does not have a datatable functionality built in.

Comment: Documentaiton for Django-tables2 will be helpful here : http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for django_table [contains examples](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html) for using a list of `dict` objects to construct a `Table`.

> An an example we’ll demonstrate using list of dicts. When defining a table it’s necessary to declare each column. If your data matches the fields in a model, columns can be declared automatically for you via the Table.Meta.model option, but for non-queryset data you’ll probably want to declare them manually:
>
> ```
> import django_tables2 as tables
>
> data = [
>     {'name': 'Bradley'},
>     {'name': 'Stevie'},
> ]
>
> class NameTable(tables.Table):
>     name = tables.Column()
>
> table = NameTable(data)
> ```

Then just use the table in your templates as before.

Comment: Could you please explain "Then just use the table in your templates as before." ?